# Docker Container Connection Issue After Exiting and Restarting

Tags: docker, filemaker

I'm using Docker Desktop for Mac to run a Docker container running FileMaker Server 19 on Ubuntu Server. When I start up Docker Engine from scratch, i.e., no daemons running, then start the container, all works as expected. I can open FileMaker's admin console in a browser and I can open the hosted database with FileMaker Pro client app.

But if I stop the container from running and quit Docker Desktop and try to run the container again it starts up but I can't establish connections to it either with the FileMaker Pro client or a browser. The solution I've found is to quit the Docker processes that continue to run in the background and make the Docker engine restart from scratch. This obviously isn't desirable and it indicates to me that something isn't configured correctly in the network connection to the container.

I'm new to Docker, so apologies in advance if I'm missing something very basic. I searched for an solution online but can't find one.

Comment: Are the networking addresses hardcoded or generated when the container is initialized?

Comment: I'm just using the "https://localhost/ ...." address (127.0.0.1) since I'm connecting to a local container. I didn't hard-code it, so it must be generated dynamically at startup. I wonder if it's a certificate or port issue. The FileMaker Server instance is using the test certificate , which isn't a real SSL certificate.

Comment: If you use the same port on localhost every time, I think it would be a certificate issue. If you want to keep the container running while the Docker daemon is down, you can try this: https://docs.docker.com/config/containers/live-restore/